# How to disable Haptic Vibrate programmatically in new devices

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Whenever the UI refreshes, we get haptic feedback on the new devices that have no home button. Is there any way to disable the haptic feedback programmatically in our iOS app.

Answer (score 0):

This is the behavior of a `UIRefreshControl`. Unfortunately, you can't disable it.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uirefreshcontrol